# How to Update Database Table Using Dropdown in Datatable

Tags: php, database

I've spent more than 48hrs trying to solve the following problem to no avail. I want to use datatable in php to update record. I am able to display record based on the user selected, However, some of the inputs are `<Select>`.

The following code populates the options but I'm getting

> Undefined Index error

```
<td><select name="class_assigned['<?php echo $id; ?>']" class="form-control 
class_assigned"><option value="<?php echo $class_assigned; ?>"><?php echo 
$class_assigned; ?> 
</option>
<?php 
$class_sql = "SELECT Class_Name FROM tbl_classes WHERE Class_Name != 
'$class_assigned'";
$class_result = $conn->query($class_sql);
if ($class_result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $class_result->fetch_assoc()) {
$class_name = $row['Class_Name'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $class_name; ?>"><?php echo $class_name; ?> 
</option>
<?php }} ?>
</select>
</td>
```

While the following code populates the Current Class_Name but I couldn't make other options appear:

```
<td><?php echo '<select name="class_assigned['.$row["id"].']" class="form-control"><option value="'.$class_assigned.'">'.$class_assigned.'</option></select>'; ?></td>
```

**What I want**:

Let's say the table displays **SS 1A**, and the user wants to update to **SS 2A**. I want the Options in the dropdown to display all classes available in `tbl_classes`.

Please have in mind that the table can display multiple rows at a time (Array).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $class_assigned is an array , in your sql query you haven't defined which index of it

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin, as per your observation, I used `$class_sql = "SELECT Class_Name FROM tbl_classes WHERE Class_Name != '$class_assigned['<?php echo $id; ?>']'";` BUT I got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in...` Can you help, please?

Comment: $class_assigned[$id] , there's no need to echo

Comment: Same problem. I'm completely out of ideas now.